# VBA Macro in powerpoint 2016 runing in normal mode not in slide show mode

Tags: vba, slideshow, powerpoint-2016

New in VBA for ppt. (used to do more Excel vba).
Below macro is really simple and works fine in normal mode , when I run it in PowerPoint's VBA editor. (Will add a blue rectangle shape in the center of the screen)

To work in slide show, I assigned the macro to a random shape through the action setting option but nothing happen really.
Thanks

```
Sub Rdmrectangle()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim SlideIndex As Long

SlideIndex = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex

Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideIndex)

Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=100, Height:=200)

With ActivePresentation.PageSetup
shp.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (shp.Width \ 2)
shp.Top = (.SlideHeight \ 2) - (shp.Height \ 2)
End With

shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue

shp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to work in slide show mode, you can work with `ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View`.

```
Sub Rdmrectangle()

    Dim sld As slide
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide

    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
        Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=100, Height:=200)

    With ActivePresentation.PageSetup
        shp.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (shp.Width \ 2)
        shp.Top = (.SlideHeight \ 2) - (shp.Height \ 2)
    End With

    shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
    shp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot !  so simple....I have been stuck on this for couple of hours.